# Ionic-Customizing Ionic titile with CSS is not working

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have made a code to customize ionic title.

**HTML**

```
<div class="styTitle">
    <ion-view title="Welcome to my App">
    <ion-view>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.styTitle ion-view title {
    font-size: 160%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-top: 11px;

}
```

On rendering on the emulator no visible changes is applied on the title.
What could be wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard way of customizing ionic title,

**HTML**

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
        <span class="
        styTitle">Welcome to my App</span>
    </ion-nav-title>
</ion-view>
```

**CSS**

```
.styTitle {
    font-size: 160%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-top: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try inline css?

Comment: <ion-view> </ionview> This is the root tag

Comment: <ion-view title="Welcome to my App" style="font-size: 160%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin-top: 11px;">
    <ion-view>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92481/discussion-between-muhsin-and-jng).

Answer (score 0):

First, your css selector is wrong (.styTitle ion-view).
Anyway that selector won't get you the title, you should try:
**ion-header-bar .title**